# react-oauth-flow + microsoft authorization error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0

I'm using react-oauth-flow to authentication using Microsoft.But It shows an error "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'scope'."  i'm passing scope parameter . Does anyone has an idea what could be the problem?

```
<OauthSender
        authorizeUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
        clientId="********************"
        scopes={["user.read"]}

        redirectUri="http://localhost:8080/add-sources"
        state={{ from: "/settings" }}
        render={({ url }) => (
          <a href={url} className="btn buttons-add-sources__auth-link">
            Connect
          </a>
        )}
      />
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: You are including `scopes` instead of `scope`